# Virtual Product change name something else

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to Echo virtual products as 'Something Else'
Where can i go ahead and do it.

Does it required to be changed in database or inside the code?

Comment: for virtual products what to do and where to change the name ?

Comment: No the product is shown as Virtual Product i want it to be seen as Virtual Design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of places where the product might be outputted.

- Category Listing
- Search Listing
- Custom Included Blocks
- Product Page

In each of these cases, you will usually have your product initialised in the block as result of a call to `$this->getProduct()` which will retrieve the current loaded product options so in order to change the output you can either change the name of the product or alter the template to suit your needs.

`design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`
`design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

Those are the two main template files that you will usually want to edit for changing the output of a page.